# E: Invalid record in the preferences file, no package header

Tags: apt, package-management, firefox

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 the other day and immediately found myself unable to use ExpressVPN on Firefox. (As I understand now, it seems to be only the browser extension that I cannot use.)

I sought help from ExpressVPN, and they advised me to remove the snap version of Firefox and install the apt version instead using these instructions:

> Step 1: Let's use Firefox PPA: sudo add-apt-repository
> ppa:mozillateam/ppa
>
> Step 2: Then, copy and paste the following code in a terminal in one
> go (don't copy-paste line by line) to prioritize the apt version of
> firefox with the snap version.
>
> echo ' 
> Package: *
>  Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam 
> Pin-Priority: 1001
> ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
>
> Step 3: Next, remove the snap version of firefox: sudo snap remove
> firefox
>
> Step 4: Install Firefox with apt.: sudo apt install firefox

As a result, I was not able to install the apt version of Firefox (Step 4 failed) and now I cannot update anything on the system. In both cases, I get the error message:

> Reading package lists... Done 
> E: Invalid record in the preferences file 
> /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox, no Package header

@Rinzwind, the content of /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox is:

> Package: * 
> Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam 
> Pin-Priority: 1001

@steeldriver, the output of `apt-cache policy | grep -A1 mozillateam | cat -A` is:

```
E: Invalid record in the preferences file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox, no Package header

 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages$
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-mozillateam,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Firefox ESR and Thunderbird stable builds,c=main,b=i386$
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net$

 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages$
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-mozillateam,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Firefox ESR and Thunderbird stable builds,c=main,b=amd64$
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net$
```

It's been several days now and ExpressVPN don't provide a solution. Can anyone help me "undo" what they instructed me to do? I figure I am better off re-installing the snap version of Firefox and using ExpressVPN via command line.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Show us the content of `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox` There is a mistake in there somewhere.  Add it to the question please Oh and I see a flaw too: somewhere you need to do `sudo apt update`

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to do that? (I'm sorry, I'm a newbie.)

Comment: it is `more /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox`

Comment: @Oryza can you also add the output of `apt-cache policy | grep -A1 mozillateam | cat -A` please?

Comment: "Can anyone help me "undo" what they instructed me to do?" remove `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox` and the error is gone

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you. I found the instructions on how to do so here: <https://www.numetopia.fr/comment-installer-firefox-au-format-deb-sur-ubuntu/>

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was caused by instructions saying to `echo -e ""` the contents of `/etc/apt/preferences.d/blah`

The problem was that the version of bash in the container didn't support `-e` and so -e was being inserted at the start of the file.